# PHP Call to undefined nameless function () on elseif statement

Tags: php, if-statement, error-handling

The following `if/elseif/else` statement is returning a `Call to undefined function  () ... on line 111` error I don't understand:

```
<?php if ( $this->NEXT_PAYMENT_DATE < date('Y-m-d') ) : ?>
<?php elseif ( ($this->LOAN_STATUS == 'V') && ($this->EXTRA_PAYMENT == '0.00') ) : ?>
<?php elseif ( ($this->LOAN_STATUS == 'V') && ($this->EXTRA_PAYMENT > '0.00') ) : ?>
<?php elseif ( $this->LOAN_STATUS == 'C' ) : ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Line 111 matches the first `elseif` statement.

`$this->` accesses the object keys with simple string data. No fields are `null`

Comment: May be you need to add ( ) to each method.

Comment: Your code seems to be okay for me, having stripped the expressions and replaced them with things like `1==1`... What does your object look like?